# CDC is not working after restoring the databse

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, change-data-capture

I have just restored my database using the below script,

```
USE [master]
GO
RESTORE DATABASE [MyDB] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL14.SQLSTANDARD\MSSQL\Backup\mydb.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, 
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5, KEEP_CDC
GO


USE MyDB
GO
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_add_job 'capture';
GO
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_add_job 'cleanup';
GO
```

Then I checked the CDC,

```
select is_tracked_by_cdc,name from sys.tables order by is_tracked_by_cdc desc
select is_cdc_enabled,name from sys.databases order by is_cdc_enabled desc
```

CDC enabled for my tables. Then I ran UPDATE script,

```
UPDATE MyTable SET Name='SomeName' where id=1
```

But found no record in cdc table,

```
SELECT * FROM [cdc].[dbo_MyTable_CT]
```

I have installed the latest Cumulative Update (CU31).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that jobs exist in SQL Agent for CDC capture and cleanup for your database.
They would look like this:

```
cdc.MyDB_capture   
cdc.MyDB_cleanup
```

And they have to be enabled, of course

Also, try disabling and re-enabling database and table for CDC, using commands from this link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/enable-and-disable-change-data-capture-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: I see these jobs `cdc.MyDB_capture` and `cdc.MyDB_cleanup` jobs available

Comment: @ImranQadirBaksh-Baloch updated answer, try re-enabling cdc

Comment: I ran `RAISERROR(22801, 10, -1); sys.sp_MScdc_capture_job` manaully and found this message `Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.`

Comment: When I ran disable command I am getting `Could not update the metadata that indicates database MyDB is not enabled for Change Data Capture. The failure occurred when executing the command '[sys].[sp_MScdc_ddl_database triggers] 'drop''. The error returned was 15517: 'Cannot execute as the database principal because the principal "dbo" does not exist, this type of principal cannot be impersonated, or you do not have permission.'. Use the action and error to determine the cause of the failure and resubmit the request.`

Comment: try using the account with "sysadmin" privilege (sa, for example)

Comment: same with sa user

Comment: Disabling removed CDC from all tables but was able to re enable for all tables again. Thanks

Comment: welcome, glad to help!